# Shiny progress bar from a global variable

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar

I have a library with custom functions and I need to use one in a shiny app. This function has a for loop inside it and I want to use the variable in that loop to update a progress bar (instead of copying the function to the server file, because I want to keep everything separate and clean). So far, I've managed to get a message to pop up when the function is running with "withProgress()", but I would like to make it even nicer showing the % of the job that is done, so the end users don't spam the run button.
This is a reproducible example of the problem:

```
library(shiny)

# Library in separate file
snail_function <- function(){
  for (i in 1:100){
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
}

# ui.R
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("1. Load Files"
           , fluidRow(actionButton("analysis", "Run analysis"))
           , fluidRow(
               plotOutput("bar")
             )
           )

    )
))

# server.R
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$analysis, {     
    output$bar <- renderPlot({
      withProgress(message = 'Running... (this may take a while)',
                   detail = 'Go get some coffee...', value = 0, {
                     snail_function()
                   })
      # do stuff
    })

  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So, I guess the question is: is there any way I could use i from the snail_function loop to set the progress in the bar? (with a global variable or something of the sort)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility to keep it a clean solution would be to add a parameter `progress` to the function, that indicates if we want to increase progress, and call `incProgress` only when this is set to `TRUE`. So when we want to run this function standalone, we can call it as `snail_function(FALSE)`. A working example is shown below, hope this helps.

---

### [image]

```
library(shiny)

# Library in separate file
snail_function <- function(progress=FALSE){
  for (i in 1:100){
    Sys.sleep(1)
    if(progress)
      incProgress(1/100)
  }
}

# ui.R
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("1. Load Files"
             , fluidRow(actionButton("analysis", "Run analysis"))
             , fluidRow(
               plotOutput("bar")
             )
    )

  )
))

# server.R
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$analysis, {     
    output$bar <- renderPlot({
      withProgress(message = 'Running... (this may take a while)',
                   detail = 'Go get some coffee...', value = 0, {
                     snail_function(progress=TRUE)
                   })
      # do stuff
    })

  })

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```